# product of thirteen 9s are different in both approach in java

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long product = 1L;
        product = (9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9);
        System.out.println(product);
        product = 9L;
        for (int i = 0; i != 12; i++) {
            product *= 9;
        }
        System.out.println(product);

    }
}
```

Output :-754810903
         2541865828329   //this one is correct

Comment: `(9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9)` is evaluated as an int and thus overflow. Try with `(9L * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9)`

Comment: This is a very similar problem to `double result=9/10;` which equals 0. Casting to the variable type is the last thing that happens

Answer (score 7):

In your first attempt, you don't make sure the result is `long`. Therefore - it overflows as `int`.

```
product = (9L * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9);
```

Answer (score 7):

That is because `int` data type is not enough to take all much that value.

Convert it to `long`.

```
product = (9L * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9);
```

Or atleast cast it first. But make sure you get a `long` data type value. Otherwise it won't work and you'll never get that result. That you wanted :)